# Существует ли Origin для линукс?

Tags: linux

Есть ли программа, аналогичная ориджину на виндоус, для линукс? (если есть может ли она воспроизводить файлы-ориджин)?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент EA ничего не сделали для воспроизведения своих игр под Linux, пробуйте steam :D

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gameolith.com/browse/

http://www.desura.com/games

http://www.jeuxlinux.fr/

http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org) можно установить на Линукс любую виндовс программу! Вайн можно установить на Линукс, если не присутствует. Он есть в altlinux.ru - отечественный Альт Линукс. forum.altlinux.org/index.php?topic=37523.0 - скачать последнюю версию (бета) с графической средой KDE5.

Пробуйте так установить и Origin.